# Is it a good practice to include created and last modified for technical articles?

Tags: website-design, best-practice, time

As a software developer, I often read technical documentation. I might be biased due to the high usage of Stack Overflow and internal tools like Confluence which are full of timestamps (almost any piece of information has a creation date).

However, every now and then I stumble across technical articles ([example](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/dark-mode)) which do not provide any timestamp information. I typically view source and search for a hidden (technical) tag that might contain some timestamp, but this is not someone using a Web site normally would normally do.

I am curious if from a UX perspective technical content creation/modification timestamps are a must or at least a good practice.

**Question:**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolutely! And I despise any article of any kind that doesn't have one.

Once, I spent several hours delving into a method for software development. After really getting into the work, I was Googling and, only then, found out that the article was far outdated and no longer usable.

Not dating a technical article, to me, is a technical blunder. The publisher and author should be shamed.